# How to use the controller variable in Views + cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

i am having the QUery in my controller actions as

```
   $report_attrid=$this->Report->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Report.report_id'=>$report_id,'Report.user_id'=>$userId)));

 $submitters['Result']['submitters']=$this->Result->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Result.form_id'=>$report_form_id)
 ,'group'=>array('Result.submitter_id')));


    foreach($submitters['Result']['submitters'] as $sub)
  {
      echo "Submitter ".$sub['Result']['submitter_id'];
      foreach($report_attrid as & $reportattrid1):

   $submitters['Result']['sub']=$this->Result->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Result.attribute_id'=>$reportattrid1['Report']['attribute_id'],'Result.submitter_id'=>$sub['Result']['submitter_id'])));

          echo "values ".$submitters['Result']['sub'][0]['Result']['value'];

         endforeach;
  }



      $this->set('submitters',$submitters);
```

which displays as

```
   Submitter 1 values NIsha values Below 5 Yrs
   Submitter 6 values Aruna values Above 10 yrs
```

where $report_attrid is used to retrieve all the reports attribute_id for the selected $report_id which is send through action..

then i am finding the submitters for the Form using $submitters['Result']['submitters'];

Then for each submitter and then foreach attribute_id that i got it from $report_attrid i am finding the values for the corresponding Attribute id and i got the values in 
  $submitters['Result']['sub'];

Everything works correct in Controller side..

But i dont know how to use all these to display the same in the View

i have tried it with

```
                                <?php echo "submitter id ".$sub['Result']['submitter_id'];?>  
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

which displays the submitter id 1 submitter id=6

Please help me to get the values also in the View..

Comment: If I may offer some advice...

Your questions consistently demonstrate little effort on your part to be easily read and understood, particularly with respect to the source code you include. You'd probably have better luck in your questions here if you spent a bit more time structuring your question (and reading the CakePHP documentation, frankly) so that it's easier to understand.

Just my two cents.

Comment: I second inkedmns remark. Quite frankly, I won't bother answering any more of Arunas questions unless and until I can see some effort being put into pinning down the source of the problem. Badly pasting pages and pages of code is not a way to ask questions, it actually shows a lack of respect for the people providing answers. **@Aruna:** Don't expect anybody to invest more energy into your project, *for free*, than yourself. Go Read The F. Manual and learn to search the Cake Google Group already to get some basic understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hey Deceze , i am new to JQuery and cakephp . Thats why i have asked the Question.. If u dont feel to answer Dont answer ...  Dont hurt learners...

Comment: @Aruna: I'm not trying to hurt you, quite the opposite, I'm trying to get you to learn. I have answered or at least commented on some of your questions in the past and read most of them, but I'm not seeing any progress on your part. After 116 questions you haven't even learnt how to properly post questions on SO (hint: it's **4 spaces** to mark code). I'm sorry if this sounds harsh and generalized, but I've seen programmers like you before, and what they need is a change of attitude and a kick in the right direction. That's what I'm trying to give you, for your own good. Read more, ask less.

Answer (score 6):

if in controller you wrote:

```
$this->set('anything', $a);
```

in view you should use:

```
<?php echo $anything;?>
```