# how to make new input field like existing input field in a form of cakephp

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

Hi i'm a beginner in cakephp I like to add one input field in admin side add.ctp I never worked with but I know about this mvc structure so i tried copy and paste existing input field 'name' I just copied the same code and only change the name as a 'sidename' it's working fine. also I've created a database field in the name of 'sidename' on corresponding table.

I'm not familiar with model and controller I just need to know only following things

1. When we add new field in a form then what all are the things and files(model,view,controller) need to be updated to save the data
2. if i want update means here in this case i'm using helper class in my code so where do i need to update
3. once it stored database means how to retrive this like in ctp file

Existing Code (i need to add new field sidename on this below code??)

```
enter code here <h3><?php echo __l('General'); ?></h3>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
            echo $this->Form->input('clone_deal_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
            //echo $this->Form->input('name',array('label' => __l('Name')));
            echo $this->Form->input('name', array('type'=>'text','class' => 'js-dealname-count {"display":"js-dealname","field":"js-dealname-count","count":"'.Configure::read('deal.dealname_count').'"}','label'=>__l('Name'), 'info' => __l('This is deal name shown in home page.') . ' ' . '<span class="character-info">' . __l('You have') . ' ' . '<span id="js-dealname-count"></span>' . ' ' . __l('characters left') . '</span>'));

            echo $this->Form->input('sidename',array('label' => __l('SideName')));

            //echo $this->Form->input('sidename', array('type'=>'text','class' => 'js-dealname-count {"display":"js-dealname","field":"js-dealname-count","count":"'.Configure::read('deal.dealname_count').'"}','label'=>__l('SideName'), 'info' => __l('This is deal name shown in side bar.') . ' ' . '<span class="character-info">' . __l('You have') . ' ' . '<span id="js-dealname-count"></span>' . ' ' . __l('characters left') . '</span>'));

            echo $this->Form->input('DealCategory', array('type'=>'select', 'multiple'=>'checkbox','id'=>'DealCategory1', 'label' => __l('Category'),'info' =>'Choose Category'));
            //echo $this->Form->input('deal_category_id', array('label' => __l('Category'),'empty' =>__l('Please Select'))); 
            if($this->Auth->user('user_type_id') == ConstUserTypes::Admin || $this->Auth->user('user_type_id') == ConstUserTypes::Employee):
                echo $this->Form->input('company_id', array('label' => __l('Merchant'),'empty' =>__l('Please Select')));
                echo $this->Form->input('company_slug', array('type' => 'hidden'));
            else:
                echo $this->Form->input('company_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
                echo $this->Form->input('company_slug', array('type' => 'hidden'));
            endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: I would recommand you first reading cakephp Cookbook first . It clears all basic concepts. Check here : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html

Comment: Did you check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426811/how-to-use-the-controller-variable-in-views-cakephp ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to the wonderful world of cakephp.

So, if you add a field to your firm and a field in the database you're basically done. Cakephp does everything else for you.  I am guessing what your model and the page you're using this info on but it will display using the same conventions as the rest of the form data.

In you controller using

```
$general = $this->General-> find ('all');
```

Will get all the rows in your database then use.

```
$this->set ('general', $general);
```

This will set a variable in the view called general.

From the view you can

```
Foreach ($general as $key => $value){
$sirname = $value['General']['sirname'];
}
```

Hope this helps.  Sorry for the format I'm on my phone wasting some time.  If you post more code we can definitely help a lot more and even write the code you need.  Specifically your controller and view.

Comment: i just want to let you know one thing i just added only in ctp file this code echo $this->Form->input('sidename',array('label' => __l('SideName')));  and then i did update my table with the new field 'sidename' you said it's enough to save the data in db . but after i'm submit the form it's not updated  on my db table

Answer (score 0):

You should use modern and better features in PHP/cakePHP like `compact()`.

```
//Here you can include many conditions to find data AND fields to select.
$variable_to_pass = $this->YourModel->find('all');    
$this->set(compact('variable_to_pass'));
```

This may not look any better than setting each variable in short run like above but let me give you Bigger picture.

```
$variable_to_pass1 = $this->YourModel->find('all');    
$variable_to_pass2 = $this->YourModel->find('all');    
$variable_to_pass3 = $this->YourModel->find('all');    
$variable_to_pass3 = $this->YourModel->find('all');    
$variable_to_pass4 = $this->YourModel->find('all');    
$variable_to_pass5 = $this->YourModel->find('all');    
$variable_to_pass6 = $this->YourModel->find('all');
$variable_to_pass7 = $this->YourModel->find('all');
$variable_to_pass8 = $this->YourModel->find('all');
$variable_to_pass9 = $this->YourModel->find('all');
```

Your OLD age approach :

```
$this->set ('variable_to_pass1', $variable_to_pass9);
$this->set ('variable_to_pass2', $variable_to_pass9);
$this->set ('variable_to_pass3', $variable_to_pass9);
$this->set ('variable_to_pass4', $variable_to_pass9);
$this->set ('variable_to_pass5', $variable_to_pass9);
$this->set ('variable_to_pass6', $variable_to_pass9);
$this->set ('variable_to_pass7', $variable_to_pass9);
$this->set ('variable_to_pass8', $variable_to_pass9);
$this->set ('variable_to_pass9', $variable_to_pass10);
```

Modern approach (causes less headache :) and less code lines too.)

```
$this->set(compact('variable_to_pass1','variable_to_pass2','variable_to_pass3','variable_to_pass4','variable_to_pass5','variable_to_pass6','variable_to_pass7','variable_to_pass8','variable_to_pass9'));
```

And in **`View`** , you can use like this , use it like a variable set in controller ,

```
echo $variable_to_pass1;
```

if its in array what you get in $variable_to_pass1 in foreach.

Comment: @Rymn , mind your language , this is NOT `nonsense`. I am giving both options ,and suggesting better options .And this is all given in cookbook. If you dont know then read it and if OP gets any issue then only ask. This is very basic level question which is already answered in Cakephp cookbook.

Comment: I guess you're right, this is a place for learning and discovery. I'd also just like to add that if everyone read the documentation this website would not exist...

Answer (score 0):

I think your question same as this Question  [cakephp new field not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116922/cakephp-new-field-not-saving)

> You need to inform cakephp that you have new fields in your db.